# mocha on test fail cannot do asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, mocha.js

I am using mocha's `runner.on("fail", postProcessFunction)` to perform some post processing when a test fails.

See: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/runner.js#L58

My issue is that within the `postProcessFunction` function i need to call a function `slowFunction` that creates a file and returns a promise. The promise takes 10 seconds to resolve and by that point, mocha has moved onto the next test or the stopped executing completely. The `slowFunction` function does not finish executing and the file never gets created.

I've tried handling the promise with `promise.then(something)` and also wrapping `postProcessFunction` in Q.async an then `yield`ing to the `slowFunction`, but I can never seem to get it to wait for the slow function to complete before continuing.

NOTE: I cannot use a global afterEach as the tests already have suite level afterEach's which would get executed before the global afterEach. I need the `slowFunction` to be performed immediately on failure

Answer (score 0):

You can detect a test failure in an `afterEach` which will allow you to use the standard mocha async setup.

```
afterEach('Test failure debug', function(){
  debug('Test result', this.currentTest)
  if (this.currentTest.state === 'failed') {
    return page.source().then(src => debug('Page source', src))
  }
})
```

In this particular case the `page` variable is scoped in the `describe` block so it's available in both the tests and the before/after helpers.

Comment: I have considered this solution but my tests already have afterEach blocks. And I would like this execute after each test and before any other afterEach

Comment: You can use async/await